# How to set ime-mode in element input angular?

Tags: angularjs, input

I read at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input

```
<input
       ng-model="{string}"
       [name="{string}"]
       [required]
       [ng-required="{boolean}"]
       [ng-minlength="{number}"]
       [ng-maxlength="{number}"]
       [ng-pattern="{string}"]
       [ng-change="{string}"]>
</input>
```

How can I set ime-mode in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to add another attributes to input (it won't cause any errors), so simply add, for example, `style="ime-mode: disabled"` (or add `class` attribute and set `ime-mode` in your css - it's better way in my opinion)

Comment: Thanks. But it can run in IE9, so I test my example on chrome and I have this issue. Maybe chrome can't use attribute style="ime-mode: disabled" in element input ?

Answer (score 0):

`ime-mode` is not supported in Chrome, Safari, or Opera. Read more about `ime-mode` and its compatibility here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ime-mode

If you do want to use it in supported versions of IE and Firefox, here are two methods:

### Use a class:

```
<input class="ime">
```

**CSS:**

```
.ime {
  ime-mode: disables;
}
```

### Inline style (not recommended):

Also note that in your markup is not valid. `input` tags are self closing and **do not** need `</input>`. Also, with angular, you probably don't need the `name` and `required` attributes. You markup should probably look like this:

```
<input
  ng-model="myModel"
  ng-required="required"
  ng-minlength="minLength"
  ng-maxlength="maxLength"
  ng-pattern="regex"
  ng-change="myChangeFunction()"
>
```

to data-bind in these values with Angular:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myModel = 'input value here';
  $scope.required = true;
  $scope.minLength = 5;
  $scope.maxLength = 20;
  $scope.regex = '/put your regex here/';
  $scope.myChangeFunction() {
    //code to run when value of input is changed
  };
});
```